# Dialogflow node.js fulfilment with multiple entities

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I hope someone can help me with this.
I have built an application that uses node.js to fulfil my intent in dialogflow.
For example, I have an intent with one required action:

[image]

It goes to my fulfilment:

```
// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'Default Welcome Intent'.
app.intent(DEFAULT_INTENT, (conv, params) => {
  let categoryId = params.category;
  let options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': apiUrl + 'questions/categories/' + categoryId + '/scenario',
    'json': true
  };

  return request(options).then(response => {
    // TODO: What happens if there is more than one question?  
    let question = response[0];
    conv.ask(question.text);
  }, error => {
    conv.ask('There was an issue with the request: ' + options.url);
  });
});
```

As you can see, this asks a question based on the **category** sent to the fulfilment.
The problem I have is that the response I want from the user is different for each question.
Once they have responded, it will also have a fulfilment that will ask another question.

Is it possible to do it this way and if so, can someone give me an example of how? If not, can someone help me work out what the alternative is?

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear. As I understand, you first want to get the category parameter and then ask a question of that category. Then when the user answers, you will have respond correct/incorrect and have a response about the answer. Then the cycle will restart. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you're using makes sense. The key thing to remember is that Intents capture what the user says, not how you handle what they say. You can influence which Intent gets triggered by setting an Input Context, and making sure you have previously set an Output Context for it.

One possible approach would be that for each question you're asking, you set a corresponding Output Context for that question. You can then have one or more Intents that take this as the Input Context. These are otherwise regular Intents, so you'd handle them normally. You might want to clear the context (by setting its lifespan to 0) after it matches, so you don't accidentally match it later.

For example, if your `question` contains, not only the text of the question, but also the context name of the question, the code might look something like this:

```
conv.ask( question.text );
conv.contexts.set( question.contextName, 5 );
```

Let's say that the `question` object looks something like this

```
{
  text: "What is your favorite color?",
  contextName: "color-favorite"
}
```

You might have a Dialogflow Intent that handles this that looks something like this

[image]

Note that the Output Context has explicitly set it to 0, which will remove it. You can also do this in your fulfillment code with something like

```
conv.contexts.delete( 'color-favorite' );
```